# List View In Libgdx

Tags: android, listview, libgdx, game-engine, android-custom-view

I have arraylist of powerUps and I want to display as a List view and whichever row user selects get that particular power for specific time.
All thing is done except I am not able to display arraylist items on listview in libgdx.
I searched a lot but didnt get any idea.
I want something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came accross with the alternative solution. implements gestureListener provided by Libgdx and used pan method.

Comment: Please add the information of where you found the solution.

Comment: please add more information and make it a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use native android listview, you should refer [this](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup)

But changing activity may not be such a good idea in most cases. So [List](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2dui#List) class in scene2d would be a great choice here. You can simply initialize it with array of items and have a selection change listener to perform power-up selection. For more, refer [this](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/List.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use `ScrollPane`

The [tutorialsface](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2016/01/scrollable-listview-in-libgdx-similar-to-android-listview-sample-example-tutorial/) implemented a sample...

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(get_long_actor___like_List());
```

and sample of the `get_long_actor___like_List()` :

```
private Actor get_long_actor___like_List() {
        Table table = new Table();
        //--------------------------------
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            table.row().center().padTop(10);
            table.add(new Label("Sample Item")).size(WIDTH, 50);
        }
        //--------------------------------
        return table;
}
```